# Cannot read property '0' of null at Za, Open Layers

Tags: jquery, openlayers

If i try to style and push points to features array, i am getting the error  `jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of null TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
        at Za (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:18:414)`

`setStyle` function below sets the style on the point and push it to features array. I can log the features array with points, but i can not add it to new `ol.source.Vector`.

//simplified javascript

```
var features = []; 

for( key of Object.keys(addrUO) ) {
        addr = addrUO['key'];
        pt = { title : addr['aui'] , lonlat : addr['lonlat'], angle : 0 } ;

        //thiss function set style on point, and push point to features array
        setStyle( pt, { type:'cr', radius:16 }, { textStrokeC:'#fff', textStrokeSize:8, textFont:'24px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif', textFillC:'#000', shapeStrokeW:5 }, features );
    }

console.log(features); //logs 8 objects 

//this line gives the error
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector( {  features: features } );

jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '0' of null TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at Za (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:18:414)
    at C.k.se (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:105:668)
    at C.k.G (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:96:642)
    at cu (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:637:368)
    at new U (https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js:636:102)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/type70711/public/js/BookBundleJS/t1c1m1.js:1823:24)
    at mightThrow (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:3570:29)
    at process (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js:3638:12) undefined

jquery.js:3636 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 79ms
```

Comment: It looks like your `features` variable is `null`. Please post where you are making this variable assignment (we can see the `addr` and `pt` assignments but not `features`)

Comment: i log the features before passing to ol.source.Vector - features contains 8 ol points with properly set styles. is  very large array of objects.

Comment: the reason was that i  i made an error pt assignment. I do not show full code here. My pt had no proper coordinates. It is difficult to understand by logging features, because they are complicated objects array. It is possible to understand by logging pt before setting styles.